# Cannot login with crypt password

Tags: php, crypt

I am developing  login and registration function for an android app. I have checked many tutorial that set password as md5, but I want a more secure way. I use `crypt()` instead of `md5`.

Howerver, I only can register and cannot login into application. How do I fix this? I replace the line

```
$password = md5($pass)
```

with

```
$password = crypt($pass)
```

Below is the code i found in example:

```
class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($username, $pass, $email){
        if($this->isUserExist($username,$email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $password = crypt($pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function userLogin($username, $pass){
        $password = crypt($pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($username){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($username, $email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Use password hash and not crypt

Comment: Check with password hash stored in your db : `crypt($usergiven, $storedindb);` after query without password

Answer (score 2):

`crypt()` will return a time-stamp hashed string when you are not giving salt.

You may add a salt and that will make hashed string become the same anytime.

```
$password = crypt($pass,"SALT_HERE");
```

However, I suggest you use `password_hash()` rather than `crypt()` if you are using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7.

It is more security than using `md5()` or `crypt()`.

Example:

```
$input = 'apple';

$hashed = password_hash($input,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//return $2y$10$1y2ie2MTlKa44vGqHIT8QeOHRR.BdtVbBj7B9He.4zQpL93cgi4Jm
//that you need to store in somewhere

//Verify the password
if(password_verify($input,$hashed)){
   //Password correct

}else{
   //Password incorrect

}
```